# why is `test.sh & | test.sh` wrong

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a bash script named `test.sh` as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    echo xxx
    sleep 1
done
```

I don't know why `./test.sh & | ./test.sh` gives me an error: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token |'`, whereas `./test.sh | ./test.sh` and `./test.sh | ./test.sh &` work.

Comment: @NasirRiley nope, it's perfectly fine to run it in the background: `{ echo yup & } | cat` or `{ ./test.sh & } | ./test.sh` are fine. It's just a limitation of the grammar.

Comment: @mosvy That isn't the same thing. If you remove the curly brackets then the error occurs with either of those commands. In the context that he's trying to run it, it's going to return that error which is why it doesn't occur when the ampersand is removed.

Comment: @NasirRiley do you mean that `{ a & } | b` won't run `a` in the background? It will.

Comment: BTW, the full shell grammar is [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10). It's obvious from following the productions that you cannot write `a & | b`, but that doesn't mean that you can't pipe the output of a bg command to a fg command. You can do that fine. Just add some extra braces.

Comment: @mosvy That literal command wouldn't run anywhere because a and b are not commands unless you've set an alias to something(I'm joking). What I mean is that the way that it functions is not the same. Perhaps I should delete my previous comment to clarify what I actually mean.

Comment: @NasirRiley It functions just as if `& |` was allowed by the grammar. Just try it. `ding(){ echo start; echo end; while sleep 1; do printf '\a' >/dev/tty; done; }; { ding & } | sed /end/q`. Extra points for killing it without `pkill` or similar ;-)

Comment: I did. It works not only with curly brackets but also with parentheses. When it's run in the same way as it is in the question, it puts the command directly into the background whereas with the curly brackets or parentheses, it puts the subshell itself into the background. I didn't do a very good job of explaining what I meant.

Comment: When running in an interactive shell, it's not a "real" background job as you can bring it back in the foreground. But in a script that makes no difference. Notice that braces (unlike parentheses) don't create a subshell by themselves. But piping a command as in `cat | cat` will, at least for the left side.

Comment: @mosvy That's better than the way that I explained it.

Comment: What would it mean to put it in the background, and to pipe its output to the next command?

Comment: script names should not end with a `.sh`. This is implementation leaking. It fails to encapsulate the implementation.

Comment: If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does not wait for the command to  finish,  and  the  return  status  is 0.  Commands separated by a ; are executed sequentially; the shell waits for each command to terminate in turn.  The return status is the exit status of the last command executed. So I think `|` is expecting some input which is not available.
`$ echo & | echo a
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simply not allowed by the shell's [grammar](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10):

> ```
> %start  complete_command
> %%
> complete_command : list separator
>                  | list
>                  ;
> list             : list separator_op and_or
>                  |                   and_or
>                  ;
> ...
>
> pipe_sequence    :                             command
>                  | pipe_sequence '|' linebreak command
>                  ;
> ...
> separator_op     : '&'
>                  | ';'
>                  ;
> ```

Notice how `&` or `;` can only terminate lists, and lists are only part of a complete_command, which cannot be part of other productions.

That's only a grammar quirk; just as `{ foo & }` is semantically similar to `foo &` (the braces, unlike parentheses, are only used to group commands, they don't create by themselves a subshell or any kind of scope), you can consider `{ foo & } | bar` to be semantically similar to `foo & | bar`, if the latter were allowed by the grammar.

So the workaround for your example is just:

```
{ ./test.sh & } | ./test.sh
```

If you run that from an interactive shell, notice that the `&` will **not** create a *background job*, but just run the command asynchronously, because the right side of a pipeline is always run in a subshell, and the commands from a subshell are run with job control disabled.

This is similar to:

```
(sleep 3600 &)
```

The asynchronous lists (commands terminated by `&`) in a subshell are run with their stdin redirected from `/dev/null` and their `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` signals ignored. They will continue to run in the background, but you cannot bring them to the foreground with `fg`, `disown` them, etc, as you can do with regular jobs. Also, you won't be notified when they were stopped or terminated.

In a script this makes absolutely no difference, since scripts are run with the job control disabled.

But if you want to pipe the output of a background *job* to a foreground *job* in an *interactive* shell, the only portable solution I can think of is to use a named pipe.

```
$ mkfifo fifo
$ command | filter1 > fifo &  # this is the background job
$ < fifo sed 10q | filter2    # this is the foreground job
```